# Do something for all controls that are checked

Tags: .net

I found this code on SO:

```
  For Each x As Control In Me.Controls
       If TypeOf x Is CheckBox Then
           DirectCast(x, CheckBox).ForeColor = Color.White
       End If
   Next
```

I have two questions please: 
**1**. Is there a way to change this code to only perform the action if the checkbox.checked = true?
**2**. Is there a way to combine this to perform this action for all groupboxes? So for example, for all groupboxes, check for checkboxes = true, and make the forecolor = color.white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it's checked after you know it's a checkbox `And CType(x, CheckBox).Checked`

```
    For Each x As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf x Is CheckBox AndAlso CType(x, CheckBox).Checked Then
            DirectCast(x, CheckBox).ForeColor = Color.White
        End If
    Next
```

To address #2 I came up with this

```
    For Each y As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf y Is GroupBox Then
            For Each x As Control In y.Controls
                If TypeOf x Is CheckBox AndAlso DirectCast(x, CheckBox).Checked Then
                    DirectCast(x, CheckBox).ForeColor = Color.White
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I made a small change in my snippet. I changed from `And` to `AndAlso` because the method would bomb whenever something else than a checkbox was being evaluated. I'm more used to C#, and I thought that `And` behaved just like `&&` but [it apparently does not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx)

Comment: Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Putting your two requests together:

```
    For Each gb As GroupBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)
        For Each cb As CheckBox In gb.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
            If cb.Checked Then
                cb.ForeColor = Color.White
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

**BUT**...this codes makes two very important assumptions:

1. All GroupBoxes are **directly** contained by the Form itself (not inside another container like a panel for instance).
2. All CheckBoxes in the GroupBoxes are **directly** contained by the GroupBoxes themselves (again, not inside another container within the GroupBoxes).